# How to use ansible_ssh_port in playbook task

Tags: ansible

My Situation is my database server is not opened with default ssh port 22, so I am trying to execute a query over port 3838.Below is the code -

```
tasks:
      - name: passive | Get MasterDB IP
        mysql_replication: mode=getslave
        register: slaveInfo

      - name: Active | Get Variable Details
        mysql_variables: variable=hostname ansible_ssh_port=3838
        delegate_to: "{{ slaveInfo.Master_Host }}"
        register: activeDbHostname
```

Ansible version is :-  1.7.2

```
TASK: [Active | Get Variable Details] *****************************************
<192.168.0.110> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root on PORT 22 TO 192.168.0.110
fatal: [example1.com -> 192.168.0.110] => {'msg': 'FAILED: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable', 'failed': True}

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

It connecting over default port 22 rather connecting on 3838 port. Please share your thoughts, If I am going wrong somewhere ...

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the value for `ansible_ssh_port` in a number of places. But you will likely want to use a dynamic inventory script.

eg. From `hosts` file:

```
[db-slave]
10.0.0.20      ansible_ssh_port=3838
```

eg. as a variable in `host_vars`:

```
---
# host_vars/10.0.0.20/default.yml
ansible_ssh_port: 3838
```

eg. in a dynamic inventory! you may use a combo of `group_vars` and tagging the instances:

```
---
# group_vars/db-slaves/default.yml
ansible_ssh_port: 3838
```

use `gce.py`, `ec2.py` or some other dynamic inventory script and group your intances in the `hosts` file:

```
[tag_db-slaves]
; this is automatically filled by ec2.py or gce.py

[db-slaves:children]
tag_db-slaves
```

Of course this will mean you need to tag the instances when you fire them up. You can find several [dynamic inventory scripts in the ansible repository](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/contrib/inventory/).

If your mysqld is running on a docker instance in the same host, I would recommend you create a custom dynamic inventory with some form of service discovery, such as using consul, etcd, zookeeper, or some custom solution using a key-value store such as redis. You can find an [introduction to dynamic inventories in the ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html).